# How to generate a clock table in reverse chronological order?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

When generating a clock-table in org-mode, is it possible to have the table generated in reverse-chronological order?  For example,

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 3 :tstart "<-1w>" :tend "<now>" :step day :fileskip0 :formatter :link t :hidefiles f :narrow 100
```

will result in something like the following:

```
Daily report: [2021-01-04 Mon]
| Headline     | Time   |
|--------------+--------|
| *Total time* | *0:00* |

Daily report: [2021-01-05 Tue]
| Headline                                          | Time   |
|---------------------------------------------------+--------|
| *Total time*                                      | *0:03* |
|---------------------------------------------------+--------|
| task 1                                            | 0:03   |

Daily report: [2021-01-06 Wed]
| Headline                                                           |   Time |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------|
| *Total time*                                                       | *3:39* |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------|
| another task                                                       | *3:39* |

...
```

How can this be made to generate a table such that the top entry is the most recent day instead of the oldest day?

Comment: One way to increase the chances of a satisfactory answer is to include the Org mode file tha you used to generate the table. That way, somebody can cut  and paste the file and try it out, without having to start from scratch - you'd be amazed what a difference that would make in the willingness of people to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-clock-table.html#The-clock-table) says:

> ‘:sort’
>
> ```
> A cons cell containing the column to sort and a sorting type
> E.g., ‘:sort (1 . ?a)’ sorts the first column alphabetically.
> ```

The sorting is done by `org-table-sort-lines` and doing `C-h f org-table-sort-lines` gives this:

> If SORTING-TYPE is specified when this function is called from a Lisp
> program, no prompting will take place.  SORTING-TYPE must be a character,
> any of (?a ?A ?n ?N ?t ?T ?f ?F) where the capital letters indicate that
> sorting should be done in reverse order.

So I would try adding

```
:sort (2 . ?T)
```

to the clocktable line. Untested and I'm not sure it works across tables: it might only work within a table.

EDIT: This indeed affects each day's table separately from all the other tables - it does not affect the order of the tables. That order is hard-wired in the function `org-clocktable-steps` in the file `org-clock.el` and, AFAICT, cannot be changed without modifying that function.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gist.github.com/takaxp/e2929aed1c33fdff2e01a708fbd5fde8) code worked for me (after setting `org-clock-table-reverse-p` to `t`).

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. Please repost it with the relevant code or a solution summary.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22368)